# Centering piece-wise function equation in LibreOffice

Tags: latex, libreoffice

I'm sorry if this is off-topic. I am using the TexMaths extension in LibreOffice and I'm attempting to center an equation. However, the equation simply gets displayed and I am unable to alter its horizontal position. So I tried to do this through LaTex but I am unable to get that to work as well. This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{center}
\[f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    sin(x) & : 0 \le x \le 2\pi\\
    -2sin(\dfrac{x}{2}) & : 2\pi < x \le 6\pi\\
    4sin(x + 2\pi) & : 6\pi < x \le 14\pi\\
    sin(x) & : x \ge 14\pi
  \end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{center}
```

But this still doesn't center it.

Comment: Equations embedded inside `\[...\]` are always centered. No need of `center` environment. BTW this is off topic. And also it is `\sin` not `sin`!

Comment: Ah, ok. It must be a LibreOffice issue then. I will also change sin to `\sin`. Sorry I'm a complete tex noob! :)

Comment: No problem. Let the question be there. in case if somebody pops up who are willing to answer....

Comment: to center the equation you just need to click on the "centered" button (default shortcut Crtl+E) like you would do for any normal text. Note that you don't need to put the math content inside `\[...\]` because texmaths already does that for you.

Comment: @dcmst Please make an answer.

Comment: @dcmst I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: This one is clearly off-topic: as noted, the TeX solution is `\[ ... \]` and so whatever is needed here is LibreOffice-specific. Perhaps try SuperUser (I could migrate, but I suspect you'll need to write the question to make it clear that this is not an issue at the 'TeX end').

Comment: @JosephWright No problem; I can edit the question after its migrated. Thanks!